# can for loop can be used in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, jsp, loops

this only gets the values corresponding to radio button named question 1 after that it returns no value. is this the correct way to use a loop or should i get individual values?

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Your Personality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss.css">
</head>

<jsp:useBean id="radioques" scope="page" class="abc.radioques" />
<%
    String q[] = new String[44];
    int j;
    for(int i=0;i<44;i++)
    {
        j=i+1; 
        q[i]=request.getParameter("question"+j);
    }
    radioques.rq(q);
%>
</html>
```

now the corresponding java class

```
package abc;
public class radioques {
public void rq(String q[]) throws JasperException, NullPointerException, Exception
{
    int ques[]=new int[44];
    int i=0;
    for(String s:q)
    {
        ques[i]=Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
    }
    int o,c,e,a,n;
    o=ques[4]+ques[9]+ques[14]+ques[19]+ques[24]+ques[29]+(6-ques[34])+ques[39]+(6-ques[40])+ques[43];
    c=ques[2]+(6-ques[7])+ques[12]+(6-ques[17])+(6-ques[22])+ques[27]+ques[32]+ques[37]+(6-ques[42]);
    e=ques[0]+(6-ques[5])+ques[10]+ques[15]+(6-ques[20])+ques[25]+(6-ques[30])+ques[35];
    a=(6-ques[1])+ques[6]+(6-ques[11])+ques[16]+ques[21]+(6-ques[26])+ques[31]+(6-ques[36])+ques[41];
    n=ques[3]+(6-ques[8])+ques[13]+ques[18]+(6-ques[23])+ques[28]+(6-ques[33])+ques[38];
    o=o/50*100;
    c=c/45*100;
    e=e/40*100;
    a=a/45*100;
    n=n/40*100;
    for(i=0;i<44;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(ques[i]);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{        
}
}
```

here the value for ques[0] is correct and value for other questions comes 0.
thanks in advance please help what seems to be the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never increment `i` in your loop here

```
int i=0;
for(String s:q)
{
    ques[i]=Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
}
```

should be

```
int i=0;
for(String s:q)
{
    ques[i]=Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
    i++;
}
```

**or**

```
int i=0;
for(String s:q)
{
    ques[i++]=Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
}
```

Comment: you're right this really was a silly question. thanks a lot though and can you help me a little more? I want to display the values corresponding to o,c,e,a,n, on the jsp page. is it possible?